# Brick-built sails for a pirate ship

Tags: building, piece-usage, shapes

I am building a Sea-Cow(70810)-like ship that of course needs sails. The sails should be larger than the Technic fairings used in the LEGO movie set, but I want to avoid cloth sails and strings.

My idea is to connect rows of white 4x6 modified tiles with studs on edges (part 6180) with hinge plates. That would give a curved rectangular sail. However, sails usually are not rectangular.

Do you have experience with sails made out of tiles or plates? How do you create the shape/curvature you have in mind? I appreciate any ideas.

**EDIT:**

After very useful suggestions by @jncraton I was able to create a prototype of sail. I found some hinges (4275/4276) to connect the rows of tiles. The brown plates are not the final solution. Now I still have to figure out how to make the sail less rectangular.

[image: Prototype1]
[image: Prototype2]

Comment: Side note: I am not the only one who misses the old finger hinges: [see this question](http://bricks.stackexchange.com/questions/4524/substitutions-for-vintage-hinges)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Great question. It sounds like you are building a fairly large ship. If the scale is large enough, brick-built sails can look quite nice. You can add shape, contour, and texture using various building techniques.

If you want to keep things simple, you could just use a single layer of bricks as was done in this basic sailboat model that was an in-store build back in 2009:

[image: in-store sailboat]

That example obviously isn't the most detailed. It's challenging to develop sail-like contours with studs on top.

Here's [one example](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/91418-limp%C3%A9rial-first-rate-ship-of-the-line/) just using plates that is similar to what you mentioned in your question:

[image: sails using plates]

Notice how it uses [wedge plates](https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?catType=P&catString=583) to round off the square corners of the sails. Wedge plates come in a variety of shapes and sizes, so that gives you some flexibility in the shape of your sail. Here's another shot showing that technique more clearly:

[image: sails from behind]

Here's a [second example](http://www.greatwesternbrickshow.com/the-journey-of-the-mayflower/) of that technique in a physical model to try to show how the sail sections can be connected using hinges:

[image: mayflower example]

Here's [another](https://www.flickr.com/photos/cstmweb/3984441013/) where layered plates are used to provide more depth and contour:

[image: layers plates with depth]

And [one more example](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?/forums/topic/104864-lego-schooner-at-arizona-science-center/) of the same technique:

[image: plates on side and tighter sail placement]

I personally like the aesthetic of studs showing in those examples, but you could also smooth your sails out using tiles and curved slopes if you'd prefer.

Comment: Oh come on, did you really edit in the same example I wanted to add, while I was writing my answer? :D

Comment: @zovits :D That's certainly what it looks like.

Comment: I've reverted my edit now that you've added this set as a separate answer. I think it works better as a separate answer. You have my upvote. :)

Comment: Thanks, but you really shouldn't have :) This question is linked from the recent Pirates of Barracuda Bay question, and the Creator Pirate Ship is a trivial association to this topic. Whether a long list or multiple single answers is better, I can't really decide, so let's leave it like it is :)

Answer (score 5):

An official example from 2020 is seen in the [31109 Pirate-Ship](https://brickset.com/sets/31109-1/Pirate-Ship) using plates and curved panels:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I haven't seen this set until now. Very simple sail construction. Interesting timing by TLG to release this shortly after the Barracuda Bay 21322 (cloth sails). I had to abandon my ship project for a "while", but with all the new pirates in the LEGO world I feel that now is a good time to get it done.